# Node.js express server freezes, only freed up by Control + C

Tags: node.js, express, cmd

So I came across an unexpected error and was baffled for awhile till I found a solution on a really [obscure github issue page](https://github.com/nodejs/node-v0.x-archive/issues/8196#issuecomment-240791311).

I have a NodeJS application running with an express server basically handling a single post point. My issue was the NodeJS application would randomly freeze and none of my requests would go through, if I noticed it I was able to go into command prompt and press "Control + c" and it would kill some hidden process and continue normal operation, if there were any calls to the post endpoint it would then execute all of them as they just queued up.

[image]
[image]

I found out the answer, was command prompt itself, when you click within the window the "Administrator: Command Prompt -..." turns into "Select Administrator: Command Prompt -...". When it has that select attribute the express server just freezes and refuses to answer any more requests.

I found out that doing "Control + c" OR pressing Esc will get rid of the "Select" keyword and then the application goes back to running normally. Please note that if you have the "Select" keyword there and you just click to another window or application, it won't get rid of it unless

I am assuming that when you click within command prompt to highlight text or copy, it spawns another process that freezes the console so that you are able to capture what is there, so if your application spawns any text to the cmd line it will hang until you are done "Select"ing the information from cmd line. This is why you need to "Control + c" to exit this marking process or press Esc to indicate you are done marking the cmd line.

**Is this something that is related to the way cmd line runs node applications? Is it related to NodeJS application? Is it related to the express server refusing to acknowledge the POST requests till done? I am really curious as to why this happens, and would like a more in-depth explanation?**

EDIT:
I just stripped most of my code out of it and tested it here, if you click into the cmd window it will not respond to the request and just hang until you control C or Esc.

```
const http = require('http');
const express = require('express');
const bodyParser = require('body-parser'); //Needed to parse content of Text
const app = express();

app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({
    extended: false
})); //Needed to parse content of Text
const {
    IncomingForm
} = require("formidable");
app.post('/plex', async (req, res) => {
    console.log("test");
    res.end('It worked!');

});

http.createServer(app).listen(1338, () => {
    console.log('Express server listening on port 1338');
});
```

Comment: Please add some code to reproduce it.

Comment: It seems like a cmd problem. Have you tried using git bash?

Comment: Nope, haven't tried git bash, I have just learned that before I leave my remote desktop I just click out of the Select cmd and it works like a charm, just was curious as to why.